Hibernate @OneToMany FetchType.LAZY is not working
I have a product class and the list of Required stock of products
I am having problems while fetching products from database
@Entity
public class Product {

@OneToMany(mappedBy =  "product",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RequiredStock> requiredStocks;

}

Once I call the findAll method from the product repository RequiredStock are fetched eagerly
public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

this is the response I got from postman
[
    {
        "id": 26,
        "requiredStocks": [
            {
                "id": 54,
                "amount": 5.0,
                "stock": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "stockName": "Sugar",
                    "quantity": 500.0,
                    "stockUnit": "GRAM",
                    "unitPrice": 25.0
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "requiredStocks": [
            {
                "id": 55,
                "amount": 2.0,
                "stock": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "stockName": "Sugar",
                    "quantity": 500.0,
                    "stockUnit": "GRAM",
                    "unitPrice": 25.0
                }
            }
        ],
       
    },
...

I do not want to fetch RequiredStocks from the api

I think the problem here is miss-understanding of how LAZY relations work. When a relation is marked as LAZY it is not retrieved along the main object (in this case Product) but when the property is accessed (when you invoke getRequiredStock.
So, I guess you are mapping the Product to a DTO or returning Products from you API, which causes the getter to be invoked and triggers the relation query.
In this case I would recommend avoid mapping requiredStock property or ignore that property using a custom DTO class without requiredStock.
Here is a more in detail SO Question about the differences of EAGER and LAZY: Difference between FetchType LAZY and EAGER in Java Persistence API?

That's usualy because during the serialization you will read the propertie requiredStocks so it fetchs data from database.
With jackson you need to add a module to manage lazy field :
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects
